# two menu same function in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, menu, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet with a Custom Menu..
I have two items different items, but with same function name ....

```
{name: "1) First MENU" , functionName: "uniqueFunction"},
{name: "2) Second MENU", functionName: "uniqueFunction"}
```

is there is a way of detect form this unique function which item Menu was select?

```
function uniqueFunction() {

if (bla bla bla) {/* FIRST MENU */}

if (bla bla bla) {/* SECOND MENU */}
}
```

Comment: What's the use case for something like this?

Comment: i want generate a custom menu from another project´s script , and these menu´s items can call one script of another project.....
resume: i dont want write my code inside editor of spreadsheet, i want dynamic menu that execute some script in another project....

Comment: Ok, so item one would run a script in the current sheet, item two would run a script in a completely different Spreadsheet? Or just another sheet in the same Spreadsheet?

Comment: always in same sheet. it is impossible. The unique way was create dinamics functions and use this names as second args , after that, use something like : arguments.callee.name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No native support for this as far as I'm aware, but there is a quick workaround I can think of:

First Menu: uniqueFunction1() / Second Menu: uniqueFunction2()

```
function uniqueFunction1() {
  uniqueFunction(1);
}

function uniqueFunction2() {
  uniqueFunction(2);
}

function uniqueFunction(menu) {

if (menu == 1) {/* FIRST MENU */}

if (menu == 2) {/* SECOND MENU */}
}
```

Comment: This implies that i need write those functions name previouly , but i need generate dynamic my menu, and i dont know how many items or it´s names

Comment: the only way that i find was create dinamic functions and then use those names as second args for menus